# Conditional bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

I have bottom navigation bar which consist of 5 icon which will redirect to 5 screen correspondingly.

The fifth icon is Account screen so when no session it must redirect to Login screen and then load the Account screen. But after login when user tap the Account icon just redirect to Account screen.

How to achieve this? How can I use if condition to determine which layout to load? Error says missing identifier expexted ')'

[image]

Comment: `PlaceholderWidget(userIsLogin ? ShowAccountPage() : ShowLoginPage()),`

Comment: @anmol.majhail wow it works never thought this way....thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with by passing an `async` function for the `onPressed` of Account icon. Your `async` function would look something like.

Example:

```
//On Home Page, for account icon pressed
Future<void> checkCredsAndNavigate(){
  bool loggedIn = _checkIfLoggedIn(); // this might be a function that gets status of user login, you can fetch from prefs, state, etc.
  if(!loggedIn){
    var data = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('YOUR_LOGIN_ROUTE_NAME');
    if(data == null){ // Check for data, will be null when user cancels login
      return;
    }
  }
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('YOUR_ACCOUNT_ROUTE_NAME');
}


//On Login page,
// On successful login call
Navigator.of(context).pop(data); // this data can be anything like user id, or just a boolean indicating successful login,etc.

//To cancel login, call
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm still confuse... how you build the bottom navigation bar and its content? I'm using body: _content[_currentIndex] where _currentIndex is which icon user tap. And I'm using placeholder to load the content